# Calculo para comprar combustivel por valor?

Tags: python, classes

Estou fazendo um programa de uma bomba de combustivel usando classes, mas nao estou sabendo fazer o calculo pra saber a quantidade de combustivel pelo valor inserido, alguem pode dar uma luz?

```
class BombaCombustivel():

    def __init__(sel, tipoComb, valorLitro, quantComb):
        self.tipoComb = tipoComb
        self.valorLitro = valorLitro
        self.quantComb = quantComb

    def abastecerPorValor(self):
        abastecerV = float(input("Valor a ser abastecido: "))
        tirarComb = **calculo aqui**
        abastecido = "Combustivel colocado: %d L"% tirarComb
        return abastecerV

    def abastecerPorLitro(self):
        abastecerL = int(input("Quantidade de litros: "))
        if abastecerL.isdigit():
            pagar = self.valorLitro * self.abastecerL
            valorPagar = "Valor a ser pago: R$ %f"% pagar

    def setAlterarValor(self):

    def setAlterarCombustivel(self):

    def setAlterarQuantidadeCombustivel(self):
```

Answer (score 3):

Certo, você precisa saber quantos litros de combustível deve colocar com X reais. Que tal dividir a quantidade de dinheiro pela preço do combustível?

Considerando que o preço do litro seja 4 reais e o motorista queira colocar 100 reais, a quantidade abastecida deverá ser 25 litros (`100/4`).

Fica por sua conta implementar no código isso ;)